# Examples of eventual counterexamples

Tags: big-picture, intuition, big-list

Define an "eventual counterexample" to be

- $P(a) = T $ for $a < n$
- $P(n) = F$
- $n$ is sufficiently large for $P(a) = T\ \ \forall a \in \mathbb{N}$ to be a 'reasonable' conjecture to make.

where 'reasonable' is open to interpretation, and similar statements for rational, real, or more abstractly ordered sets for $n$ to belong to are acceptable answers.

What are some examples of eventual counterexamples, famous or otherwise, and do different eventual counterexamples share any common features? Could we build an 'early warning system' set of heuristics for seemingly plausible theorems?

edit: The Polya conjecture is a good example of what I was trying to get at, but answers are not restricted to number theory or any one area.

Comment: Your question seems interesting. Could you put in at least one elementary example to explain your formal definition?

Comment: Thanks Colin, I updated to include an example and the answers so far are all on track for what I intended.

Comment: This question is somewhat related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/13601/a-weird-sequence-with-a-non-integral-term

Comment: Kevin,it came out somewhat garbled on my end-want to check it so it comes out smooth in math? I can't quite get the definition.

Comment: I J Kennedy edited the title, changing "phenomena" to "phenomenon". Q Q J has now changed it back. I think "phenomenon" is better. It is an interesting phenomenon that there are eventual counterexamples. 

Comment: Gerry, I see what you mean but I think it is less presumptuous to suppose there is some possible plurality to the idea.

Comment: By the way... shouldn't it be "The phenonenON of eventual counterexamples"?

Comment: Oh. Looking at the edit history  shows that's been, hmm, debated :)

Comment: Mariano, since I ask "Do different eventual counterexamples share any common features?", the possibility of different classes of general behaviour means that the plural seems more appropriate to me.  

Comment: The last 5 edits have consisted solely of toggling phenomena/phenomenon. Maybe we should just change the title to "Some eventual counterexamples".

Comment: I broke the toggling switch, and hope this will be permanent.

Comment: There are lots of answers that basically contain only the name of the result and a link to a paper/webpage; I find them very unhelpful and would like to invite the authors to put at least a quick explanation in the text of their answers. In general, link-only answers are frowned upon on many stack exchange websites.

Comment: If anybody ever _disproves_ the Riemann Hypothesis, he/she would not only receive one million dollars, but could also write an answer to this question that would get a high reputation score.

Comment: Technically, the Clay Institute only guarantees a payout for a positive resolution to one of its seven problems, not a counterexample (though explicit exceptions are made for Navier-Stokes and P != NP): http://www.claymath.org/millennium-problems/rules-millennium-prizes

Comment: Is the following an eventual counterexample? For all positive integers n there is a (non-trivial) statement true for 1, 2, 3, ..., n but false for n+1.

Comment: The ring of integers of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[n]{2})$ is not always $\Bbb Z[\sqrt[n]{2}]$. It is true for $n < 1000$, but not for $n=1093$. See https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/integersradical.pdf.

Comment: Theme song for this question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOCsdhzo6Jg

Comment: I wonder whether native speakers of French and German will misunderstand the word "eventual" because of its resemblance to the French "eventuel", which Germans have borrowed?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

It was once conjectured that factors of $x^n-1$ over the rationals had no coefficient exceeding 1 in absolute value. The first counterexample comes at $n=105$.

Comment: And in fact these coefficients (eventually!!) grow exponentially fast.  See https://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/~ada26/cyclotomic/ for a nice compendium of cyclotomic polynomials with enormous coefficients.

Comment: I often heard this, but I've never seen a citation. Who conjectured that?

Comment: @Kevin, I don't know. I thought I once came across a reference to someone who computed up to $n=100$ in the year 1940 or so, stopped there and made the conjecture, but I haven't had any luck tracking it down. Noticing the breakdown at 105 is attributed to Migotti, 1883, and a proof that the coefficients can be arbitrarily large is due to Schur, published by Emma Lehmer in 1936, so if I'm right about the computations in 1940 then they were done by someone who was out of the loop and perhaps it's best not to embarrass any descendants by dredging up the reference. 

Comment: I seem to recall that some book begins by pointing out this particular conjecture and the counterexample (and says the coefficient that's not 1 is 2).  What book would that be?

Comment: @Gerry: I know where I read it (annual collection "In the world of mathematics", vol 12 or 13, published in Kiev ca 1984, in Ukrainian). The article went on talking about Euler's pentagonal theorem and the recurrence for $\sigma(n)$, so I am stuck with the impression that Euler also conjectured the cyclotomic fact.

Comment: This "conjecture", as well as the first counterexample, are due to the following fcat (Theorem): if $m$ has not more than two odd prime factors, then the cyclotomic polynomial $\phi_m$ has coefficients in $\{-1,0,1\}$. The first $m$ with three odd prime factors is $105$.

Comment: @JacquesCarette your link to cyclotomic polynomials with large coefficients has died.

Comment: The CECM link can still be found at http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/~ada26/cyclotomic/ . Might want to ask Andrew Arnold (or Mike Monagan) to put it back somewhere more 'live'.

Comment: I used mod magic to put the live link back into Jacques highly-upvoted comment, but I'm leaving the most recent comments about the fact the original link broke.

Answer (score 167):

The least positive integer for which the equality
$$ \left\lceil \frac{2}{2^{1/n}-1}\right\rceil = \left\lfloor                
      \frac{2n}{\log 2} \right\rfloor $$
fails is $n=777,\!451,\!915,\!729,\!368$. See https://oeis.org/A129935.

Another example that I like is the number $f(n)$ of inequivalent differentiable structures on $\mathbb{R}^n$. We have $f(n)=1$ if $n\neq 4$, while $f(4)=c$, the cardinality of the continuum.

Answer (score 84):

The essence of the phenomenon of eventual counterexamples is that a certain pattern that holds among small numbers, turns out not to be universal. In the very best examples, such as the examples provided in the other answers, which I have enjoyed very much, what we have is an easily described property $P(n)$, whose first failing instance is very large in comparison. Indeed, the quality of answer might be measured by the difference between the size of the 
description of the property and the size of the first failing instance of it. When an easily described property holds for a very long time and then suddenly fails at some very large number, we are surprised. Therefore, to my mind the phenomenon of eventual counterexamples is intimately wrapped up with the possibility of providing very short descriptions of enormous numbers.

Surely we are all able easily to provide short descriptions of some very large numbers, such as $2^{100}$ or $2^{2^{100!}}$. In order to go beyond exponentiation and factorials, we might make use of other easily described functions exhibiting even more enormous growth. The [Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function), for example, defined by a simple one-line recursion, has diagonal values 1, 3, 7, 61, $2^{2^{2^{65536}}}$, with the next value $A(5)$ mind-bogglingly huge.

All such examples, short descriptions of large numbers, can be systematically transformed into instances of eventual counterexamples. For if $d$ is a short description of an enormous number $N$, then the property $P(k)=$"$k$ does not exhibit $d$" is easily described and holds for all values $k$ below $N$, but not of $N$ itself. Thus, it does very well by the quality measure I mentioned above.

So to my mind, the real issue is: what are the largest numbers that you can describe by a very short description?

This question can be made precise by requiring the description to be expressible in a particular formal language. Once the language is rich enough, however, this problem will certainly wade into interesting foundational waters, for the question of whether a given description actually succeeds in describing a number---for example, "the length of the shortest proof of a contradiction in ZFC"---may be independent of our basic axioms, even if it is enormous.

Comment: This is a great perspective

Comment: Yes, but it seems that one has to take into account also the difficulty of generating the underlying sequence. For example, the polynomial x^2−x+41 gives primes up to x=40, and 40 is not a big number by "absolute" measure, it is big compared to say other polynomials in generating primes.

Comment: 2^2^2^65536 isn't `mind-bogglingly huge'?! 

Comment: This reminds me of the nice blog post: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week236.html

Comment: Another relevant blog post: http://www.scottaaronson.com/writings/bignumbers.html

Comment: And my blog post on a "largest number contest" I recently conducted: http://jdh.hamkins.org/largest-number-contest/

Comment: I think the aspect that you are missing is it needs to difficult to discover the counterexample without simply trying every value in sequence.  In the examples you gave, the counterexample is obvious given the description of the property.

Its the pure mathematics equivalent of the Busy Beaver Problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver

Comment: @WolfLink I think you haven't grasped the enormous generality of my point. In general, Kolmogorov complexity is not computable, and so there isn't in general a way to compute whether a given complex description has a much simpler description. But when it does, then this provides an instance of the phenomenon.

Answer (score 70):

[Strong Law of Small Numbers](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Guy697-712.pdf) by Guy.

Steve

Comment: Item 13: D.H. & Emma Lehmer discovered that $2^n\equiv 3 (\mod n)$ for $n=4700063497,$ but for no smaller $n>1.$

Comment: There is a part 2 of Guy's paper, Richard K Guy, The second strong law of small numbers, Math Mag 63 (1990) 3-20, MR 91a:11001 (and also by the same author, Graphs and the strong law of small numbers, in Graph Theory, Combinatorics, and Applications, Vol 2, Wiley, 1991, pages 597-614). 

Comment: Do you mean $n > 2$?  Last I checked we have $2^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{2}$.

Comment: This is wonderful! I've been going through and thinking about which problems I have intuition for yet no rigorous proof for. It's making me wonder whether I can show that there are certain ways in which we can't construct sequences of only primes.

Comment: @David Mandell Freeman: Huh? Isn't the left side even and the right side odd?

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Here's a working link: http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Guy697-712.pdf

Answer (score 64):

In reference to the [Prime Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) (then Conjecture) both Gauss and Riemann further conjectured that $\pi(n) < \operatorname{Li}(n)$ (where $\pi(n)$ is the number of primes from $1$ to $n$ and $\operatorname{Li}(n)$ is the logarithmic integral, $\int_2^n \frac{1}{\ln(t)} \, dt$).

Although it has been proven that this does not hold (Littlewood), that there exists some $n$ such that $\pi(n) \geq \operatorname{Li}(n)$, the first $n$ where this takes place is so huge no-one has worked it out yet (allegedly). The number is known as [Skewes' Number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SkewesNumber.html).  It is known to be between $10^{14}$ and $1.39822\times 10^{316}$, and strongly believed to be about $1.397162914\times 10^{316}$.  (References at the foregoing link.)

Comment: Is Skewes' number the first $n$ where it happens, or is it the (much larger) bound Skewes found for the first such $n$?

Comment: It is the first $n$ where it happens. There are actually two `Skewes' Number's, each assuming whether the Riemann Hypothesis is true or false respectively. See the link to mathworld in the post.

Comment: Remember reading in a book by Ogilvy (Excursions in Number Theory) following theorem of Littlewood :  the function  $\pi(n)-$Li$(n)$ changes sign infinitely often (I read it in my undergraduate  days, and never seen that book again)

Answer (score 60):

I'm trying to reconstruct an example I saw somewhere some years back. It goes something like this: 
$\gcd(n^5-5,(n+1)^5-5)=1$ is true for $n=1,2,\dots,1435389$ but fails for $n=1435390$ (when the gcd is 1968751).

Comment: I found a place which has this example, and it has many more examples: http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/96/smallnums

Comment: Pretty impressive! Specifically, gcd(n^17+9, (n+1)^17+9)=1 for all n up to some crazy explicit number, the number of digits of which I couldn't even count. This begs the question, is there a reasonably simple proof that this gcd isn't always 1?

Comment: The resultant of $x^{17}+9$ and $(x+1)^{17}+9$ is some (large) integer, D. So there are polynomials $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ with integer coefficients and degree at most 16 such that 
$a(x)(x^{17)+9)-b(x)((x+1)^{17}+9)=D$. Now reduce modulo a prime p dividing D to get the equation 
$a(x)(x^{17)+9)=b(x)((x+1)^{17}+9)$ in Z_p[x]. Now $x^{17}+9$ has 17 distinct zeros in Z_p, and they can't all be zeros of a(x), so at least one of them is a zero of $(x+1)^{17}+9$, and you're done. 

Comment: I don't understand why sometimes I get to see a math preview and sometimes not. I didn't see one when I made the comment above and it appears that I left out some closing braces, so some formulas are missing. I don't know how to edit my comment to put those braces in, but it doesn't matter, since my argument was more complicated than necessary anyway. 

If the resultant of two polynomials is divisible by some prime p, then the two polynomials have a common factor over the integers modulo p. These polynomials either split completely or are irreducible, so they must have a common linear factor.

Comment: Since the link in Gerry Myerson's comment is dead now, I will add the link to version in the [Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20140928192643/http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/96/smallnums).

Answer (score 55):

Freeman Dyson observed in my presence that the sequence with initial condition $a_0=3,a_1=0,a_2=2$, and recurrence $a_{n+3}=a_{n+1}+a_{n}$ almost has the property that $n\mid a_n$ if and only if $n$ is prime or 1, except that it doesn't.

He challenged us (grad students) to explain this ``near-phenomenon'', as it seems too close to being too good to be true to be coincidence. I've never seen an explanation.

Since this is Math Overflow, I'll give the spoiler, the first counterexample is $n=521^2=271441$.

Comment: a_n is the sum of the nth powers of the roots of x^3 = x + 1, so the divisibility follows from the fact that the Frobenius map permutes the roots of a polynomial.  Are you asking for an explanation of the failure of the converse?  I see no reason to expect the converse to be true.

Comment: I guess if anything needs an explanation it's why does it take so long for a counterexample to turn up. These numbers are (I think) the "Perrin pseudoprimes," see http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A013998

Comment: Suppose for example that n = pq for p, q distinct primes and let a, b, c be the roots of x^3 = x + 1.  In order for a^n + b^n + c^n to be divisible by n we require that a^q + b^q + c^q be divisible by p and a^p + b^p + c^p be divisible by q.  This is just highly unlikely; one might expect that a^p, b^p, c^p and a^q, b^q, c^q are just the roots of some random irreducible cubic polynomial mod q and mod p, respectively.  Replacing x^3 = x + 1 by an irreducible polynomial of higher degree might conceivably lead to even larger pseudoprimes.  

Comment: Here is a related perspective.  a_n counts the number of closed walks of length n on a certain graph G on 3 vertices; the cyclic group Z/nZ acts on these walks in the obvious way and the residue of a_n mod n is the number of walks lying in an orbit which is not of full size.  When n is prime, orbits can either have size p or size 1 and the latter can't occur if there are no loops in G, which there aren't.  When n is composite, the situation is much more complicated and it would be very surprising if the number of walks in non-full orbits was still divisible by n.  

Comment: For example, the combinatorics make it clear that a_{p^k} is congruent to a_{p^{k-1}} mod p^k.  Hence if a_p isn't divisible by p^2 then a_{p^k} isn't divisible by p^k for any k > 1.  And there's no reason to expect a_p to be divisible by p^2; these primes might be called generalized Wieferich primes.  

Comment: I think the spirit of the observation was akin to observing that ``$e^{\pi \sqrt{163}}$ is an integer, except that it isn't.'' Or that ``the image of $0,1,\dots$, under $x\mapsto x^2-x+41$ is always prime, except that it isn't.'' Now, nobody would expect these criteria hold, but it is shocking that such simple expressions can come so close. And ultimately, there is deeper meaning to the observations. In the current phenomenon, no informed number theorist would suspect that the sequence detects primes perfectly, but it is shocking (to me, at least) that so simple a sequence comes so close.

Comment: One might wonder whether there is a Perrin pseudoprime that is also a Carmichael number. There are such, but the first is 7045248121, according to http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A078512

Answer (score 48):

A famous example is the isomorphism problem for integral group rings: suppose $G$ and $H$ are two finite groups of order $n$ such that $\mathbb{Z}G \cong \mathbb{Z}H$ does it mean that $G \cong H$? It was proved to be true for many cases and for many $n$'s and I think it was believed to be true in all cases. Nonetheless, eventually a counter example was found, see
Hertweck, Martin. *A Counterexample to the Isomorphism Problem for Integral Group Rings.* Annals of Mathematics, vol. 154, no. 1, 2001, pp. 115–138. https://www.jstor.org/stable/3062112.

Comment: Could this give an answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/52169/adjacency-matrices-of-graphs ?

Answer (score 40):

The numbers 12, 121, 1211, 12111, 121111, etc., are all composite - until you get to the one with 138 digits, that's a prime. Saw this in a talk Lenny Jones gave at the New Orleans meeting earlier this month.

Comment: If you take a random sequence that grows like 12*10^n, the prime number theorem says you have something like a 13% chance of making it to 137 digits without seeing a prime. So, even if you've seen that the first 137 numbers of the form 12111...11 are composite, is the conjecture that *all* such numbers are composite really a reasonable one to make?

Comment: @Vectornaut, while I think your point is valid, it needs to be adjusted slightly, because the sequence is far from random. For example, in a pattern like that you won't get any primes unless the final digits are odd, and that increases the chance that any individual term is prime, which in turn decreases by quite a bit the chance that 137 terms are composite.

Comment: 40, 403, 4033, 40333, ... are all composite until you reach 483 3's;  the first prime of 45, 451, 4511, 45111, ...  has 772 1's.

Answer (score 34):

The [Borwein Integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein_integral) are integrals of products of the sinc function. They exhibit certain "apparent patterns" which, while eventually breaking down, are actually indicative of something larger at work. (The example given on the Wikipedia page is a good one.)

Comment: Bailey and Borwein give a few other examples in the "coincidences and fraud" section of their May 2005 *Notices* article: http://www.ams.org/notices/200505/fea-borwein.pdf

Answer (score 34):

Any finite loop space has the rational cohomology of a Lie group -- up to rank 65. From then on, there are counterexamples in every dimension. The smallest known *dimension* of a counterexampe is 1250, but whatever the actual smallest dimension is, counterexamples will occur in every dimension after that.

Comment: And, for the record, a finite loop space is a finite CW-complex $X$ that is homotopy equivalent to $\Omega Y$ for some space $Y$.

Answer (score 29):

In answering another MathOverflow question on Graham's number, I quoted from Harvey Friedman's Enormous Numbers in Real Life.  Perhaps eventual counterexamples bear some relation to proof strength in certain systems of logic?  Anyway, that example there could be rephrased to fit the current question.

Suppose I look at strings on three symbols, and given a word w of length n I look
at subwords of the form (forgive the AWK notation) `spc[i] = substr(w,i,i+1)`, i.e.
those substrings starting at the $i$th character going for length $i+1$ characters.
So `spc[1]` gets the first two characters of $w$, `spc[2] == w[2]w[3]w[4]`, and so on.

I manage to find, for every $n$ that I can compute, a string $w_n$ that I use for $w$ above such that for $0 < i < j \leq \frac{n}{2}$, `spc[i]` is not a subsequence of `spc[j]`.  Others find such examples for even larger values of $n$.  It would be reasonable for me to believe I could find arbitrarily long strings with this property.

Enter Harvey Friedman:

"**Theorem 8.1**. Let $k \geq 1$. There is a longest finite sequence
$x_1, \dots ,x_n$ from $\{ 1, \dots ,k \}$ such that for no $i < j \leq \frac{n}{2}$ is $x_i, \dots ,x_{2i}$ a subsequence of $x_j , \dots ,x_{2j}$.

For $k \geq 1$, let $n(k)$ be the length of this longest finite
sequence.

Paul Sally runs a program for gifted high school students at
the University of Chicago.

He asked them to find $n(1), n(2), n(3)$. They all got $n(1) =
3$. One got $n(2) = 11$. Nobody reported much on $n(3)$.
I then started to ask several mathematicians to give an
estimate on $n(3)$, some of them very famous. I got guesses
like this:
$60, 100, 150, 200, 300$.

They were not in combinatorics. Recently I asked Lovasz,
telling him about these five guesses. He guessed $20000$.

**Theorem 8.2**. $n(3) > A(7,184)$.

Lovasz wins, as his guess is closer to $A(7,184)$ than the other guesses.

Recall the discussion about $A(5,5)$ being incomprehensibly large. With the help of computer investigations (with R. Dougherty), I got:

**Theorem 8.3**. $n(3) > A(7198, 158386)$.

A good upper bound for $n(3)$ is work in progress. Crude result:
$A(n,n)$, where $n = A(5,5).$"

Here $A(n,n)$ is defined earlier in Friedman's paper as an Ackermann-like sequence.

I suspect $n(3)$ squishes Graham's number quite unlike a galactic black hole absorbing a prion or even a quark.

EDIT: I have been corrected; in the squishing hierarchy, $n(4)$ squishes Graham's number, which squishes $n(3)$.  Again, unlike any physical realization I can imagine. END EDIT

The moral here is: "Don't jump to conclusions without a sufficiently strong proof system as back up".

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.02.17

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation $A(m,n)$. Is it the entry of a particular adjacency matrix or something?

Comment: Sorry.  Above I mentioned A(n,n) after the quotation as being an Ackermann like sequence.  You should check the paper for his particular definition of A(n,m), but it involves iterated composition.  The "kicker" part of the definition is A(n+1,m+1) = A(n, A(n+1,m)), or something like that.  A(4,n) is something like 2 tetrated n times, so A(4,5) is already 2^65536.  You can check out the MathOverflow question on Graham's number for more info.

Comment: In the above mentioned post on Graham's number, it was pointed out that Graham's number is bigger than n(3) but smaller than n(4).  I apologize for getting the index wrong.

Answer (score 27):

The [Mertens conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_conjecture).

Comment: And related, a counterexample to the Riemann hypothesis, if it exists, should be a prime example.

Comment: I think that Littlewood's result on the difference between the number of primes <x and li(x) was a surprise to many.

Answer (score 24):

Let $a_1=1$, $a_{n+1}=(1+a_1^2+a_2^2+\dots+a_n^2)/n$. Are all terms integer? No, the first non-integer is $a_{44}$. I do not know neither reference (my source is private communication by Dmitry Rostovsky, and he does not remember where is it from), nor deep reason (if they exist) why first 43 terms are integer.

Comment: This is discussed in E15 of Guy, Unsolved Problems In Number Theory. He says F Gobel found the recursion yielded many integers, but Hendrik Lenstra found that first counterexample. Guy gives generalizations and many references. 

Comment: Following up some of those references, I found a claim that $a_1=11$, $a_{n+1}=a_n(a_n^2+n)/(n+1)$ gives integers up to (but not beyond) $n=600$ or so.

Answer (score 22):

Smallest counterexample to "There is no positive integer $n$ such that the concatenation of (the decimal representation of) $n$ with itself is a square" is $n=13223140496$, according to https://oeis.org/A102567; $1322314049613223140496 = 36363636364^2$.

Comment: Are all those 3s and 6s on the RHS an accident?

Comment: Yes - and no. If you look at http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A106497 which is the sequence of right sides, they are all highly patterned numbers, related to the decimal expansions of $a/11$ and $a/7$ for various $a$. Whether they must be of this form, I do not know. 

Comment: @DavidMandellFreeman If $(10^n+1) m$ is square for $m<10^n$, then $10^n+1$ must have a square divisor, say $10^n+1 = s^2 t$ and $m = r^2 t$. Then $\sqrt{(10^n+1)m} = rst \approx 10^n (r/s)$. So the RHS will look very close to a decimal expansion of $r/s$. The first non-squarefree numbers of the form $10^n+1$ are $11^2 | 10^{11}+1$ and $7^2 | 10^{21}+1$. If you search further, I'm sure other denominators occur.

Comment: For example,$13^2|10^{39}+1$ and $384615384615384615384615384615384615385^2 = (147928994082840236686390532544378698225)*(10^{39}+1)$, reflecting that $5/13 = 0.384615\cdots$.

Comment: Secondary eventual counterexample: the solutions all _seem_ to have an odd number of digits in each "half" of the square number. An even number of digits in each half would be at least 136 digits!

Answer (score 21):

Here's another one, maybe mostly of historical interest. Fermat once conjectured that all numbers of the form
$$
p=2^{2^n}+1
$$
are prime, which he had the means to verify up to $n=4$. It took more than 100 years until Euler showed that this fails at $n=5$. Today we still don't know if there are any other Fermat primes, so quite possibly Fermat's conjecture fails in the worst possible way.

Answer (score 20):

**Shapiro inequality:** Let $x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n,x_{n+1},x_{n+2}$ be positive real numbers with $x_{n+1}=x_1$ and $x_{n+2}=x_2$. Now the inequality
$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \dfrac{x_i}{x_{i+1}+x_{i+2}} \geq \dfrac{n}{2}$ must be true if $n<14$ or if $n\leq 23$ and $n$ is odd. So $n=14$ is the first $n$ where a counterexample can be found. I know that 14 is not that large a number, but remember that for each $n$ we have a problem with a lot of freedom.

Answer (score 20):

Recently I saw that in any $2,3,4,5,\ldots$ consecutive integers, one of them is comprime to the rest, then I conjectured that it should be trivially true for **any** $k$ consecutive integers, but I didn't able to prove this and I asked this question in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720497/one-of-any-consecutive-integers-is-coprime-to-the-rest#1720497), and I surprised by Noah Schweber answer! It's true only for $1,2,\ldots,16$ and the first counterexample is the sequence of length $17$ beginning with $2184$.
There are infinitely many counterexamples for $17\leq k $.
https://oeis.org/A090318/internal

Comment: There are infinitely many counterexamples for _any_ $k\ge 17$.

Comment: In the MSE link you gave the answer by Noah Schweber claimed that Brauer proved it. [In this another answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699375/s-s-pillai-on-consecutive-integers-research-paper/1699384#1699384) he links to the Brauer's paper with a proof.

Comment: @user236182 In this article showed that there is **a** counterexample for $n\geq17$ but you said **infinitely** counter example.

Comment: If there is one counterexample $x+1, \ldots, x+k$, there are infinitely many: just add any common multiple of $x+1, \ldots, x+k$.

Comment: This is closely related to the Erdos-Woods numbers, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erdős–Woods_number

Comment: @GerryMyerson's [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15444/examples-of-eventual-counterexamples/134319#comment581383_234875), clickably:  [Erdös–Woods number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erdős–Woods_number).

Answer (score 18):

This is a bit tongue-in-cheek, but what about Special Relativity? In this case let property $P(x), x\in \mathbb{R}$ be the property that a given velocity $x$ is attainable. After all, Galilean Transforms allow one to change to a frame moving at an arbitrary velocity. Only Einstein's interpretation of the discoveries of Lorenz and Poincaré allowed for us to realize that property $P$ is only true if $x \in [-3 \times 10^8, 3 \times 10^8]$

Answer (score 17):

One of my favourite examples in this context is the following: Define a sequence
$(s_n)$ by $s_1=8$, $s_2=55$ and for $n\geq3$ $s_n$ the smallest integer such
that $s_n/s_{n-1}>s_{n-1}/s_{n-2}$ so that $s_3=379$ as $379/55>55/8$. Then we
have $s_n=6s_{n-1}+7s_{n-2}-5s_{n-3}-6s_{n-4}$ for $5\leq n\leq11056$ but not
for $n=11057$ (I have lost track of the name of the person to whom this is due,
but it is, nowadays, easily verified on a computer).

Comment: This may have come out of David Boyd's research on PV and Salem numbers. 

Comment: Thank you, Gerry! I was struggling to remember the name of the object it reminded me of: Pisot sequence, $a_{n+1}=N(a_n^2/a_{n-1}),$ where $N$ is the nearest integer function (round down if the fractional part is exactly 1/2). Boyd showed that many Pisot sequences aren't linearly recurrent.

Comment: I found the source; David W Boyd, Linear recurrence relations for some generalized Pisot sequences, Advances In Number Theory 333-340, Oxford University Press, 1993, MR 96i:11017. Boyd had several earlier papers on Pisot sequences, and this example may also be given in one of the earlier papers. 

Comment: Umm, not a big deal or anything, but I was the one who found this example, and told David Boyd about it, back in 1990.

Answer (score 15):

How about [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3943)?

Answer (score 15):

I've had fun showing $1,2,4,8,16,31$ to people, both math and non-math people, actually. ([OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000127))

Comment: You can really throw people off by showing it to them as $1, 2, 4, 8, 16, \ldots, 256, \ldots$ - they don't realize that the 256 isn't in the right place for the sequence to be powers of two.

Answer (score 14):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned Graeco-Latin Squares https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeco-Latin_square

Euler showed these exist for $n$ odd, or any multiple of 4.  As none exist for $n=2$ or $6$, he conjectured that none exist for any $n\equiv 2 (mod 4)$.

As it happens, such exist for any $n\geq 3$ except $6$. This is quite a famous example, if small.

Answer (score 13):

The first counterexample to the [second Hardy-Littlewood conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy-Littlewood_conjecture) is expected to occur somewhere between $10^{174}$ and $10^{1199}$ (at least, according to the references from the Wikipedia page), though it has not yet been definitively established that such a counterexample exists.

Comment: Some problem with Wikipedia link :(

Comment: I fixed the link (hopefully...)

Answer (score 13):

This came up a few years ago from an error I noticed in the OEIS database.  For all $0 \leq n \leq 58$, the numerator of $\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{2^{k+1}-1}{k+1}$ is equal to the numerator of $\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{\binom{n}{k}}{(k+1)^2}$.  This fails first at $n=59$ and then at $n=1519, 7814, \ldots$.  See [A134652](https://oeis.org/A134652).

Answer (score 13):

I'm late to the party, but here's one from algebraic number theory.

The ring of integers of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[n]2)$ is exactly $\mathbb Z[\sqrt[n]2]$ for $2\leq n \leq 1092$. At $n =1093$, the ring of integers is bigger. One can show that $\displaystyle\frac{(\sqrt[1093]{2}-2)^{1092}}{1093}$ is an algebraic integer, but is not in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt[1093]2]$.

Keith Conrad has a nice paper on this: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/integersradical.pdf

Comment: This is correlated with the fact that for $p=1093$, the number $2$ is a $p$- power residue $\bmod p^2$. Thereby, the claimed fraction can be given a defined integer residue $\bmod 1093$, surmounting an obstacle that stops analogous expressions for smaller primes.

Answer (score 12):

D. H. Lehmer showed that the first prime value of the Ramanujan tau-function, defined by $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \tau(n) q^n = q \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^n)^{24} = q - 24q^2 + 252q^3 - 1472q^4 + \dots,$$ occurs at the [63001](https://www.oeis.org/A135430)st term.  This is slightly less surprising when one knows that prime values can only occur for odd square inputs.

Comment: When does the first zero value occur? :P 

Comment: As far as I know, the non-vanishing question is still open.  I haven't heard of any lower bounds that are better than Lehmer's $10^{15}$.

Answer (score 12):

I had a [conjecture](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305125/is-it-true-that-for-any-two-integers-with-the-same-least-prime-factor-there-mus/3459621#3459621) that for any two natural numbers with the same least prime factor, there must be at least one number in between them with a higher least prime factor. It seemed very robust for reasonably-sized numbers and empirical trends suggested it would hold for arbitrarily large numbers as well.

Months later, I found a paper giving some freshly computed large terms for the Jacobsthal primorial function $h(n)$, and using those, ferreted out a counterexample starting at $$724968762211953720363081773921156853174119094876349.$$

I think this may be the smallest counterexample; even if not, you can show that if there is one smaller, it can't be by much. Until I found this, I would have said I was certain my conjecture was correct. Lesson learned!

Comment: Very neat example! I believe the interval $7310131732015251470110369$ to $7310131732015251470110511$ should be a smaller counterexample. The endpoints both have least prime factor $71$, and each number in between is divisible by something less than $71$. The prime $71$ is the smallest one which can be the least prime factor of the endpoints, but this is probably not the best example using it. I also cannot rule out the possibility of using a slightly larger prime like $73$ instead.

Comment: @MatthewBolan Wow, well done! I guess I stand corrected. It would be nice if you have the time to write that up as an answer on my [relevant post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305125/is-it-true-that-for-any-two-integers-with-the-same-least-prime-factor-there-mus/3459621#3459621), ideally explaining something about how you found it. I know I'm curious.

Answer (score 11):

[The Pólya conjecture.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_conjecture)

Answer (score 11):

From [the Wikipedia category of disproved conjectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Disproved_conjectures):

- Borsuk's conjecture
- The Chinese hypothesis
- Euler's sum of powers conjecture

Answer (score 11):

In [this thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11517/computer-algebra-errors) search down for the answer by sigfpe .

Comment: Direct link: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11517/computer-algebra-errors/11607#11607

Answer (score 11):

Hmmm ... as yet, no examples have been given from geometry or dynamics.  So here's one.

Supposing that we interpret $P(a)=T$ for $a<n$ to mean "geometric objects have property $P$ for most objects that arise naturally", and let $P$ be the ergodic property, then the [Kolmogorov–Arnold–Moser theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Arnold%E2%80%93Moser_theorem) suggests itself as providing the "eventual counterexample."

Domokos Szasz' article "Boltzmann's Ergodic Hypothesis, a Conjecture for Centuries?" (1994) provides an historical overview of the long slow process by which dynamical conjectures that for centuries were widely believed, were eventually proved to be wrong.

---

Another (related) answer:

In Conway's LIFE game, if the starting patterns are arranged in lexical order, the first self-replicating   life-form (known at present) is Andrew J. Wade's [Gemini](http://pentadecathlon.com/lifeNews/2010/05/oblique_life_spaceship_created.html).

The *Gemini* life-form can be viewed as the first (known) counter-example to the hypothesis "life-forms are not self-replicating".   The lexical index of *Gemini* (as computed from its bounding-box) is $2^{4217807\times4220191}$ ... obviously too large to find by a blind search.

It seems to be generically true of life-forms (both biological-type and Conway-type)—and perhaps formal proofs too?—that special properties are emergent at very large lexical order-number of starting structures.

Answer (score 11):

Robert Baillie has a paper on arxiv today (https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3943) which shows how in principle one can construct examples of formulae which hold for $N=0,1,2,\ldots,k$, for arbitrarily large $k$, then fail for all larger $N$.

His largest example holds with $k\approx \exp(\exp(\exp(\exp(\exp(\exp(e))))))$.

Comment: That's the same paper Seva linked to in his answer, posted about 3 hours earlier than this one. 

Answer (score 11):

This one is a little bit a joke. If you calculate the powers $2^k$, it seems that the leading (decimal) digit can never be $7$.

Actually, the first digit happens to be $7$ not before $2^{46}$.

Comment: 9 beats 7, holding out until $2^{53}$.

Comment: It's a joke because by taking logs, it should be immediately obvious that the density will be $\log_{10} 8 - \log_{10} 7$.

Comment: If you look at the data, a better conjecture to make is that the leading digits of $2^n$ are periodic with period 10: they cycle through 2, 4, 8, 1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 5, 1 over and over for the first 40 powers of 2.  The first time this pattern breaks is at $2^{46}$, where the expected 6 is a 7, as Denis points out.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a recent one I didn't see on either page.  The following are true statements:

$\displaystyle{ \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t} \, dt = \frac{\pi}{2} }$
$\displaystyle{ \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t} \, \frac{\sin \left(\frac{t}{101}\right)}{\frac{t}{101}} \, dt = \frac{\pi}{2} }$
$\displaystyle{ \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t} \, \frac{\sin \left(\frac{t}{101}\right)}{\frac{t}{101}} \, \frac{\sin \left(\frac{t}{201}\right)}{\frac{t}{201}} \, dt = \frac{\pi}{2} }$
$\displaystyle{ \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t} \, \frac{\sin \left(\frac{t}{101}\right)}{\frac{t}{101}} \, \frac{\sin \left(\frac{t}{201}\right)}{\frac{t}{201}} \, \frac{\sin \left(\frac{t}{301}\right)}{\frac{t}{301}} \, dt = \frac{\pi}{2} }$

Is it true that

$\forall n,\displaystyle{ \int_0^\infty \prod_0^n\frac{\sin \left(\frac{t}{100n+1}\right)}{\frac{t}{100n+1}} \, dt = \frac{\pi}{2} }$

?

---

No, it's not.  However, you could have a computer calculating this for the rest of your life and never find a counter-example. **The first counter-example for n has 43 digits.**

I found this example [here](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2018/09/20/patterns-that-eventually-fail/). It was specially constructed to have a large counter-example - the page gives a way to construct similar statements with arbitrarily large counter-examples.

Answer (score 8):

R. M. Grassl and A. P. Mullhaupt, "Hook and Shifted Hook Numbers", Discrete Mathematics, Volume 79, Number 2, January (1990) pp. 153-167

"An infinite number of counter examples is provided for the conjecture that a shifted tableau shape is uniquely determined by its multiset of shifted hook numbers. Nevertheless, the previous conjecture of the first author that there was only one example of nonuniqueness is discussed and it is shown that it is «almost» true, based on computer search."

There were about five million examples before the counterexample, and approximately 1 mole of examples before the next counterexample is thought to occur.

Comment: The way I read the abstract (at http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6V00-45D9TMB-4&_user=21981&_coverDate=01%2F15%2F1990&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_acct=C000002378&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=21981&md5=3a8a35426f83a45151d4e6fd3c745aa1), the 2nd counterexample came up somewhere in the first five million cases, and it was the 3rd counterexample that was expected to be a mole away. 

Comment: I think you're right. It's been a while since I looked at that; I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 7):

The [Busemann-Petty Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Busemann-PettyProblem.html).

Answer (score 7):

The sequence $$1, 19, 9243, 540569, 71564873\dots$$ giving the absolute value of the real part of $(19+98i)^n$, $n=0,1,\dots$ is monotone increasing – until you get to $n=484$. The real part of $(19+98i)^{484}$ is $4.2157\times10^{965}$ (to five significant figures), which is less than the real part of $(19+98i)^{483}$, which is $4.2176\times10^{965}$.

This comes from Bruce Reznick, On the nonmonotonicity of (|Im(zn)|), Journal of Number Theory Volume 78, Issue 1, Pages 144-148 (September 1999), MR1706901 (2001a:11134).

Comment: [Reznick - On the non-monotonicity of $\lvert\operatorname{Im}(z^n)\rvert$](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X99923946) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1706901)).

Comment: There isn't anything special about $19+98i$ here, by the way - the results of the paper imply that this holds for powers of any Gaussian integer $a+bi$ except those with $a = 0, b = 0$, or $|a| = |b|$.  The paper was published in 1999 and presumably written in 1998.

Comment: @Michael, yes, I have a preprint from Bruce, dated 12 June 1998.

Answer (score 6):

The [De Giorgi conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.3141) is true for dimensions $\leq 8$. I guess this doesn't really count because De Giorgi himself only conjectured it for those dimensions based on the fact that Bernstein Theorem of minimal graphs is only true in dimensions $\leq 8$...

(To stay within the realm of geometry, if someone finds a counterexample to the positive mass theorem in high dimensions, that would be an example too.)

Answer (score 6):

Let $Q(n), n \in \mathbb{N}$ denote [Hofstadter's Q sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter_sequence#Hofstadter_Q_sequence) --
i.e. $Q(1) = Q(2) = 1$, and $Q(n) = Q(n-Q(n-1)) + Q(n-Q(n-2))$ for $n > 2$.
Then we have:

- $Q(3 \cdot 2^0) = 2$,
- $Q(3 \cdot 2^1) = 4$,
- $Q(3 \cdot 2^2) = 8$,
- $Q(3 \cdot 2^3) = 16$,
- $Q(3 \cdot 2^4) = 32$,
- $Q(3 \cdot 2^5) = 64$,
- $Q(3 \cdot 2^6) = 128$,
- $Q(3 \cdot 2^7) = 256$,
- $Q(3 \cdot 2^8) = 512$

Guess something? -- Well, NO! --

- $Q(3 \cdot 2^9) = 808$,
- $Q(3 \cdot 2^{10}) = 1627$,
- $Q(3 \cdot 2^{11}) = 3127$,
- $Q(3 \cdot 2^{12}) = 6113$

Answer (score 5):

It was a conjecture that number of three-dimensional Young diagram of volume $n$ is counted by the generating function $\prod(1-x^n)^{-n(n+1)/2}$, as analogous facts are true for usual Young diagrams (Euler) and two-dimensional (Macmahon?) It is so for first few coefficients, but fails in general.

Comment: MacMahon conjectured, but did not prove, the two-dimensional case. 

Answer (score 5):

Here is one from geometry where the number is small, yet larger than most people would guess.

Proposition:  A regular polygon having $n$ sides ($n=3, 4, ...$) can be constructed with a marked straightedge and compasses.  We might suppose that a regular $11$-gon would be the first counterexample.  But Benjamin and Snyder proved otherwise in 2014[1], so the real first counterexample is not before $n = 23$.

**Reference**

1. ELLIOT BENJAMIN and C. SNYDER (2014). On the construction of the regular hendecagon by marked ruler and compass . Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society, 156, pp 409-424 [doi:10.1017/S0305004113000753](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004113000753))

Comment: So this is not in fact a counterexample? The result of Benjamin and Snyder is that $11$ is *not* a counterexample to the statement labeled a "Proposition" (which apparently has the status of an open conjecture)?

Comment: That's why we had to push the first counterexample to 23.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the homomorphism defined by
$\varphi(1) = 121; \ \varphi(2) = 12221$.  This homomorphism
has a infinite fixed point $r = r(0) r(1) r(2) \cdots $,
which you obtain by iterating $\varphi$,
starting with $1$.

Then the sequence $r$ satisfies the equality
$r(16n+1) = r(64n+1)$ for $n = 0, 1, \ldots, 1864134$, but not
for $n = 1864135$.

Comment: How is $\varphi$ a homomorphism, and of what?

Comment: It is a homomorphism on the free 2-generated monoid of strings on the 'letters' 1 and 2 (which can be extended to the blackboard bold Nth power of the alphabet to give one-sided infinite strngs). Gerhard "Benefits Of Universal Algebra Training" Paseman, 2016.04.09.

Comment: I take it that $r_i$ and $r(i)$ are use interchangeably...

Answer (score 4):

Conditions:

> $n$ such that $\ Ord_n(2) \mid n-1 $ and $\ Ord_n(2) - 1 = 2^x,n \in    2 \mathbb{N}+1,\ x \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$.

$\ Ord_n(b)\triangleq \min\{k\in\mathbb{N}:n|b^k-1\}$

$1227133513$  is the smallest known number matching the conditions which is not a prime number.

More info about $n=1227133513$:

> $Ord_n(2) = 33$ and $n\ |\ 2^{33} - 1$.

> $n-1=2^33^211\cdot31\cdot151\cdot331$

> $n=(2^{33}-1)/7=23 \cdot 89 \cdot 599479$. $\ 599479\ $ is one of the primes that  match the conditions.

> $n$'s base-$2$ representation is 10 occurrences of $100$, followed by $1$. Its base-$8$ representation is $11111111111$.

In the second of the sources listed below, another example $n=6657848551$ was given. Here

> $Ord_n(2)=1025=2^{10}+1=5^2\cdot41$

> $n-1=2\cdot3^25^217\cdot41\cdot21227$

> $n=601\cdot1801\cdot 6151$

See:

> https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813293/are-there-composite-numbers-matching-the-conditions

> https://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=19393

Comment: To my surprise, 1227133513 appears in 17 sequences at the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. Only one seems at all related to its appearance here, namely, http://oeis.org/A086250 6657848551 is (currently) absent from the OEIS.

Answer (score 4):

I had a nice conjecture, but Robert Davis gave a counter-example to that.
It boils down to the following:

Let  the conditions $x_1\geq x_2 \geq \dots \geq x_p \geq 0$ and $x_1+\dots+x_d=n$
define the partition polytope $P(n,d)$.
Let $\hat P(n,d)$ be the convex hull of the lattice points in $P(n,d)$.

Whenever $n+d\leq 25$, every integer point in the dilation $2\hat P(n,d)$
can be written as a sum of two integer points in $\hat P(n,d)$,
but for $n=16$, $d=10$ there is a counterexample.
The point 
$$({6, 6, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1} ) \in 2\hat P(16,10)$$
is not expressible as a sum of two integer points in $P(16,10)$.

Answer (score 4):

To extend my previous answer, in the world of polytopes, there are plenty of eventual counter-examples.

I ran into several such counter-examples in my research, and put them together [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.00647) (arxiv).

Some of the smallest counter-examples I have show up in dimensions >100.

I saw another comment regarding hooks, which have a polytope interpretation (hook values determine a volume of a certain polytope).
It is natural to ask if hook values determine the Ehrhart polynomial also, but this fails for a pair of partitions of size 16.

Answer (score 4):

The Laver tables give and will continue to give examples of sentences $\forall n P(n)$ which are known to be false under strong large cardinal assumptions but where no such $n$ where $P(n)$ is false has been explicitly found nor is known to exist under any weaker large cardinal assumptions. Since set theorists typically believe in either the consistency or the existence of large cardinals and since the algebraic structures that arise from the sufficiently strong large cardinal embeddings support the existence of such strong large cardinal hypotheses. Furthermore, since the classical Laver tables and similar structures are constructed using a double recursion that resembles the Ackermann function, one should expect the Laver tables to produce many examples of eventual counterexamples.

The Laver tables should be thought of as a combinatorial object that has many features such that under large cardinal assumptions, there will always come a point where these features no longer hold.

All these results on the final matrix and the Laver-like algebras are my own while the results on the classical Laver tables are not my own.

> Classical Laver tables

The $n$-th classical Laver table is the unique algebra $A_{n}=(\{1,\dots,2^{n}\},*_{n})$ where $x*_{n}(y*_{n}z)=(x*_{n}y)*_{n}(x*_{n}z),x*_{n}1=x+1\mod 2^{n}$ for $x,y,z\in\{1,\dots,2^{n}\}$.

Under strong large cardinal hypotheses, the classical Laver tables should be thought of as algebraic structures consisting of patterns that will all eventually end but only after a very long time.

If $x\in A_{n}$, then let $o_{n}(x)$ be the least number $m$ with $x*_{n}2^{m}=2^{n}$. If $x\in\{1,\dots,2^{n}\}$, then let $\vartheta_{n}(x)$ be the least number $m$ with $x*_{n+1}m>2^{n}$.

Fact: (Randall Dougherty) If $n<\mathrm{Ack}(9,\mathrm{Ack}(8,\mathrm{Ack}(8,254)))$, then $o_{n}(1)<5$.

Eventual counterexamples: (Richard Laver) If for all $n$, there exists an $n$-huge cardinal, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}o_{n}(1)\rightarrow\infty$. No upper bound for the least $n$ with $o_{n}(1)=5$ has proven in ZFC. This fact the source of many eventual counterexamples one may have about the classical Laver tables.

Fact: If $n<9$ and $o_{n}(x)=o_{n+1}(x)=o_{n+2}(x)$, then $\vartheta_{n+1}(x)\leq\vartheta_{n}(x)$. Thomas Jech conjectured that this result holds for all $n$, but a suitably motivated human could even have computed a counterexample by hand, so this conjecture is easily disproven.

Eventual counterexample: $o_{9}(34)=o_{10}(34)=o_{11}(34)$, but $\vartheta_{9}(34)=5,\vartheta_{10}(34)=8$.

Eventual counterexample: A linear ordering $\preceq$ on $A_{n}$ is said to be compatible with $A_{n}$ if
$y\preceq z\Rightarrow x*_{n}y\preceq x*_{n}z$. If $n>0$ and $\preceq$ is a linear ordering on $A_{n}$ compatible with
$A_{n}$, then define a linear ordering $\preceq'$ on $A_{n-1}$ by letting $x\preceq^{'}y$ iff $x+2^{n-1}\preceq x+2^{n-1}$.

Let $P(n)$ denote the statement that for every linear ordering $\preceq^{\sharp}$ on $A_{n-1}$, there is a linear ordering $\preceq$ on
$A_{n}$ with $\preceq'=\preceq^{\sharp}$. Then $P(n)$ is true for $n\leq 17$, but $P(18)$ is false.

> The final matrix

If $A$ is a set, then let $(A^{\leq 2^{n}})^{+}$ denote the collection of all non-empty strings from the alphabet $A$ with length at most $n$. Then $(A^{\leq 2^{n}})^{+}$ can be endowed with a unique operation $*_{n}$ that satisfies the following rules:

1. $\mathbf{x}*_{n}(\mathbf{y}*_{n}\mathbf{z})=(\mathbf{x}*_{n}\mathbf{y})*_{n}(\mathbf{x}*_{n}\mathbf{z})$ for $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y},\mathbf{z}\in(A^{\leq 2^{n}})^{+}$.
2. $\mathbf{x}*_{n}\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{y}$ whenever $|\mathbf{x}|=2^{n}$, and
3. $\mathbf{x}*_{n}a=\mathbf{x}a$ whenever $|\mathbf{x}|<2^{n},a\in A$.

Let $FM_{n}^{-}:\{1,\dots,2^{n}\}\times\{1,\dots,2^{n}\}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ be the mapping where if $r$ is the least natural number where $|a_{-1}\dots a_{-i}*_{n}a_{1}\dots a_{r}|=2^{n}$, then
$$a_{-1}\dots a_{-i}*_{n}a_{1}\dots a_{r}=a_{FM_{n}^{-}(i,1)}\dots a_{FM_{n}^{-}(i,2^{n})}.$$ We shall call $FM_{n}^{-}$ the final matrix.

The motivation behind the data $FM_{n}^{-}$ is that all the combinatorial complexity about the operation $*_{n}$ is coded inside the function  $FM_{n}^{-}$.

1. For $n<7$, if $FM_{n}^{-}(x,y)>0$ and $y\leq 2^{n-1}$, then 
   $FM_{n}^{-}(x,y+2^{n-1})>0$ as well. However,
   $FM_{7}^{+}(8,16)=1,FM_{7}^{+}(8,16+2^{6})=-4$.
2. If $n<9$ and $FM_{n}^{-}(i,j)>0,FM_{n}^{-}(i,j+1)>0$, then $FM_{n}^{-}(i,j+1)=FM_{n}^{-}(i,j)+1$. But

$FM_{9}^{-}(8,175)=1,FM_{9}^{-}(8,176)=3$,

$FM_{9}^{-}(8,191)=1,FM_{9}^{-}(8,192)=4,$ and

$FM_{9}^{-}(8,143)=1,FM_{9}^{-}(8,144)=1$.

3. If $n<11$ and $FM_{n}^{-}(i,j)>0,FM_{n}^{-}(i,j+1)>0$, then $FM_{n}^{-}(i,j+1)\geq FM_{n}^{-}(i,j)-1,$ but
   $FM_{11}^{-}(8,255)=3,FM_{11}^{-}(8,256)=1$.
4. If $n<7,FM_{n}^{-}(x,y)>0$, then
   $\gcd(2^{n},x,y)\leq\gcd(2^{n},FM_{n}^{-}(x,y))$, but
   $FM_{7}^{-}(8,16)=1$.

The following counterexamples form $FM_{n}^{-}$ have only been established through large cardinal hypotheses.

Let $(x)_{a}$ be the unique natural number where
$x=(x)_{a}\mod a$ and $1\leq (x)_{a}\leq a$.

Let $ST_{0}=\{(1,1)\}$. Let $(x,y)\in ST_{n+1}$ if and only if
$((x)_{2^{n}},(y)_{2^{n}})\in ST_{n}$ and either $x\leq 2^{n}$ or $y>2^{n}$.

$\textbf{Hypothesis:}$ $(SE_{n})$

Suppose that $i,j\in\{0,\ldots,2^{n}-1\}$. Then

1. $FM_{2^{n}}^{-}(2^{i},2^{j})>0$ if and only if $i$ is even, $j$ is odd, and $(i+1,j)\in \mathrm{ST}_{n}$.
2. If $FM_{2^{n}}^{-}(2^{i},2^{j})>0$, then $FM_{2^{n}}^{-}(2^{i},2^{j})=2^{i}.$
3. Suppose that $FM_{2^{n}}^{-}(2^{i},2^{j})<0$. Then $FM_{2^{n}}^{-}(2^{i},2^{j})=-2^{k}$ for some $k$.
   Furthermore,

i. if $j$ is odd, then $0<k\leq i$, and
$$FM_{2^{n}}^{-}(2^{i'},2^{j})=-2^{k}$$
for $k\leq i'\leq i$, and
$$FM_{2^{n}}^{-}(2^{k-1},2^{j})=2^{k-1}.$$

ii. if $j$ is even and $FM_{2^{n}}^{-}(2^{i},2^{j+1})>0$, then
$$FM_{2^{n}}^{-}(2^{i},2^{j})=-FM_{2^{n}}^{-}(2^{i},2^{j+1}).$$

iii. if $j$ is even and $FM_{2^{n}}^{-}(2^{i},2^{j+1})<0$, then
$$2\cdot FM_{2^{n}}^{-}(2^{i},2^{j})=FM_{2^{n}}^{-}(2^{i},2^{j+1}).$$
.
The following table gives a picture for the hypothesis $SE_{4}$.
The $(i,j)$-th entry in the following table is set to be $+\log_{2}(FM_{16}^{+}(2^{i},2^{j})$ whenever $FM_{16}^{+}(2^{i},2^{j})>0$ and it is set to be $-\log_{2}(-FM_{16}^{+}(2^{i},2^{j})$ whenever $FM_{16}^{+}(2^{i},2^{j})<0$.

$\begin{array}{r|rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
 &0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16\\
\hline
0&-0&+0&-0&+0&-0&+0&-0&+0&-0&+0&-0&+0&-0&+0&-0&+0&4\\
1&-0&-1&-0&-1&-0&-1&-0&-1&-0&-1&-0&-1&-0&-1&-0&-1&4\\
2&-0&-1&-2&2&-0&-1&-2&2&-0&-1&-2&2&-0&-1&-2&2&4\\
3&-0&-1&-2&-3&-0&-1&-2&-3&-0&-1&-2&-3&-0&-1&-2&-3&4\\
4&-0&-1&-2&-3&-4&4&-4&4&-0&-1&-2&-3&-4&4&-4&4&7\\
5&-0&-1&-2&-3&-4&-5&-4&-5&-0&-1&-2&-3&-4&-5&-4&-5&8\\
6&-0&-1&-2&-3&-4&-5&-6&6&-0&-1&-2&-3&-4&-5&-6&6&8\\
7&-0&-1&-2&-3&-4&-5&-6&-7&-0&-1&-2&-3&-4&-5&-6&-7&8\\
8&-0&-1&-2&-3&-4&-5&-6&-7&-8&8&-8&8&-8&8&-8&8&11\\
9&-0&-1&-2&-3&-4&-5&-6&-7&-8&-9&-8&-9&-8&-9&-8&-9&12\\
10&-0&-1&-2&-3&-4&-5&-6&-7&-8&-9&-10&10&-8&-9&-10&10&12\\
11&-0&-1&-2&-3&-4&-5&-6&-7&-8&-9&-10&-11&-8&-9&-10&-11&12\\
12&-0&-1&-2&-3&-4&-5&-6&-7&-8&-9&-10&-11&-12&12&-12&12&14\\
13&-0&-1&-2&-3&-4&-5&-6&-7&-8&-9&-10&-11&-12&-13&-12&-13&14\\
14&-0&-1&-2&-3&-4&-5&-6&-7&-8&-9&-10&-11&-12&-13&-14&14&15\\
15&-0&-1&-2&-3&-4&-5&-6&-7&-8&-9&-10&-11&-12&-13&-14&-15&15\\
16&+0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16
\end{array}$

Theorem: If there exists a rank-into-rank cardinal, then there is a natural number $n$ where $SE_{n}$ is false.

I can currently calculate an arbitrary entry in the table $FM_{n}^{-}$ whenever $n\leq 48$. With modern computational technology, it should be possible to calculate arbitrary entries in $FM_{n}^{-}$ for $n\leq 96$. I have experimentally verified $SE_{n}$ for $n\leq 5$, and it is feasible to verify $SE_{6}$ as soon as someone gets the time to do so. I suspect that the least $n$ where $SE_{n}$ fails is exceedingly large. Perhaps, $SE_{n}$ is larger than the running time of any computer program of length at most $10^{100}$ characters which can be proven to terminate in "ZFC+There is a supercompact cardinal" with a proof of length at most $10^{1000}$.

$\textbf{Hypothesis:}$ ($EP_{n}$) Suppose that $r$ is a natural number and $x<2^{2^{r}}-1$. Then $FM_{n}^{-}(x,2^{y})=FM_{n}^{-}(x,2^{z})$ whenever $y=z\mod 2^{r}$ and $\max(y,z)<j\cdot 2^{r}<n$ for some $j$.

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ If there exists a rank-into-rank cardinal, then there is a natural number $n$ where $EP_{n}$ is false.

No known counterexample to $EP_{n}$ is known to exist in ZFC.

> Laver-like counterexamples

Define the Fibonacci terms $t_{n}(x,y)$ for all $n\geq 1$ by letting $t_{1}(x,y)=y,t_{2}(x,y)=x,t_{n+2}(x,y)=t_{n+1}(x,y)*t_{n}(x,y)$.

We say that an algebra $(X,*,1)$ that satisfies the identities $x*1=1,1*x=x,x*(y*z)=(x*y)*(x*z)$ is permutative if for all $x,y\in X$, there is some $n$ where $t_{n}(x,y)=1$. Define $x^{0}*y=y,x^{n+1}*y=x*(x^{n}*y)$ for $n\geq 0$. Define $\mathrm{crit}(x)\leq\mathrm{crit}(y)$ if and only if there Is some $n$ with $x^{n}*y=1$. Then $\{\mathrm{crit}(x)\mid x\in X\}$ is always linearly ordered set. There is a unique operation $\circ$ on $X$ where $(X,\circ,1)$ is a monoid and $x\circ y=(x*y)\circ x$ for all $x,y\in X$.

$\mathbf{Theorem:}$ Suppose that all large cardinals exist. Suppose that $s,t,u$ are terms in the language $*,\circ$ with $s,t$ unary and $u$ binary. Suppose furthermore that
$A_{1}\models\mathrm{crit}(s(x))=\mathrm{crit}(t(x))=\mathrm{crit}(x)$. Then there is a finite permutative algebra $(X,*,1)$ along with $x,y\in X$

1. $s(x)*x=s(y)*y$
2. $u(x,y)\neq 1$
3. $\mathrm{crit}(x)=\mathrm{crit}(y)$
4. $\mathrm{crit}(r*r*s)\leq\mathrm{crit}(r*s)$ for all $r,s\in X$.

In the above theorem, for some very simple terms $u,s,t$, I have not been able to compute examples of such algebras.

Besides these counterexamples which are known to exist, there are many different kinds of Laver-like algebras which I conjecture to exist but for which I have no proof even if I assume large cardinals exist and for which I conjecture the first example of such algebra is extremely large.

Answer (score 4):

A nice eventual counterexample comes from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3991987):
For every integer $n\ge 2$ , define $$f(n):=\Phi_n(n)$$ where $\Phi(n)$ is the $n$ th cyclotomic polynomial. Then $f(n)$ is squarefree for all $n<28341$, but $$283411^2\mid \Phi_{28341}(28341).$$

Answer (score 3):

$1223$ is the smallest odd prime which does not divide any [Carmichael number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number)
with $3$ prime factors -- cf. e.g. [here](https://www.gap-system.org/DevelopersPages/StefanKohl/problems/cm3fact.txt).

Answer (score 3):

While there is no known counterexample to the assumption that the probabilistic
[Baillie–PSW primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baillie%E2%80%93PSW_primality_test) is actually a proper primality test, there is strong
evidence that there exist such counterexamples. -- In 1984, [Carl Pomerance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Pomerance) has
even given a heuristic argument (see [here](http://www.pseudoprime.com/dopo.pdf)) that for any $\epsilon > 0$ and large
enough $x$, the number of composites $\leq x$ failing the test is larger than
$x^{1-\epsilon}$ -- yet none is known so far.

Answer (score 3):

Ed Sandifer has a nice [article](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/hedi/HEDI-2005-08.pdf) for the MAA wherein he describes Euler's attempts to derive a recursion for the central trinomial coefficients ([OEIS A002426](https://oeis.org/A002426)).

Euler lets the reader think he has derived such a formula as $a_{n+1}=3a_n-F_n(F_n+1)$ ([OEIS A011769](https://oeis.org/A011769)), but they disagree after the 9th term.

Euler calls this eventual counterexample an "**EXEMPLUM MEMORABILE INDUCTIONIS FALLACIS**," which has a pretty good ring to it.

Answer (score 2):

The equation $x^3+y^3=313^2z^3$ (or the closely-related equation $313(x^3+y^3)=z^3$) has attracted some attention. All the results I will mention can be found at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1613119/a-diophantine-equation-with-only-titanic-solutions

Elkies found the smallest solution in integers, $$\small x_0 = 355507307842882624593086325021133856149447336710120844428552934573043094018915
289363\\
\small y_0 = -354602746692986709129018423204648314355484458881941451025238387384142099383045
862152 \\
\small z_0 =1517122651849438712721950935044230084378368307868200665761294465082177989014675811$$

Note that $y_0<0$. Tito Piezas III reports a solution in positive integers with $z$ a bit larger than $10^{21388}$. Allan MacLeod reports a solution in positive integers with roughly $6770$ digits, although it's not clear to me that MacLeod is solving exactly the same equation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_m$ denote the symmetric group on $n$ letters and let $P(m)$ denote the size of the outer automorphism group of $S_m$, i.e., the size of the quotient $\mathrm{Aut}/\mathrm{Inn}$ where $\mathrm{Inn}$ is the group of inner automorphisms (the ones induced by conjugation by an element of the group).
Then
$$\begin{cases} P(m)=1 &\text{ if } m\neq 6 \\ P(m)=2 &\text{ if } m= 6. \end{cases}$$
Of course, the "counter example" is not for a particularly large value, but only for a single one.

Comment: Then it's not a case of eventual counterexamples, is it?

Comment: Dear Harry, I was sure someone would bring up this issue and even thought about making a comment on that. Sure. You are correct. Nevertheless, I believe this is a surprising fact. If you really want an "eventual counter example", then consider the function $Q(m)=P([m/N])$ for any $N\gg 0$. The philosophy of the question is, I think, about phenomena that seems to conform to a certain pattern for many many examples but does not do so for all examples. This certainly qualifies for that. If it still bothers your sense of justice, please feel free to vote it down. Cheers!

Comment: It's an eventual counterexample if you start at infinity and work your way down. 

Comment: I second Gerry's comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

Nate Eldredge has mentioned the Skewes number,and in fact it is not the only place where we can speak of counterexamples, within number theory:
The Riemann hypothesis is a fairly good case where counterexamples have been sought for through huge amounts of computations. In the paper "The $10^{13}$ ﬁrst zeros of the Riemann Zeta function, and zeros computation at very large height" by Xavier Gourdon and Patrick Demichel (using an algorithm by Andrew Odlyzko), the authors have checked out the truth of the Riemann hypothesis (that all non-trivial zeroes of $\zeta(s)$ are encountered whenever $s = 1/2 + \mathcal{i} T, \ T \in \mathbb{R}$), from the first, up to precisely the $10^{13}$th zero. In the same paper Riemann hypothesis has been tested numerically, checking out some $10^{9}$ zeroes from heights of $T$ as large as $10^{24}$. Now then, in spite of the fact that we have available such large amount of numerical evidence, this does not constitute a proof of the Riemann hypothesis, simply because the amount of zeroes is infinite, and there is no telling (yet) on whether we might encounter some day an instance of $\zeta(s) = 0, s = a + \mathcal{i} T, a\neq 1/2$, and we might as well wait long time for a numerical counterexample, much in the same philosophy mentioned in Nate Eldredge's answer, and all this  would constitute the answer to the second part of your first question: "do different eventual counterexamples share any common features?". In the cases discussed by Eldredge and in here, the common feature of the (possible) counterexamples is that in both cases a gigantic amount of numerical evidence was (has been, in the case of the Riemann hypothesis) amassed, and still there was (there is) the possibility of finding a counterexample.

Numerical calculations are still useful, tough, because there has been instances where the calculation does not have to be carried out that far. For example, the so-called Fermat's Little Theorem states that all numbers of the form $2^{2^{n}}+1$ are primes, and Fermat carried up calculations up to $n=4$. However, when $n=5$, Euler proved that such was no longer the case, since this "Fermat Number" can be factored into 641 and 6700417.

As for your second question:
"Could we build an 'early warning system' set of heuristics for seemingly plausible theorems?"
 I am going to answer with something that must be taken "with a pinch of salt", but it is the closest I can think of an answer. I want you to refer to the p vs np problem (Polynomial time computer solving as opposite to Non-polynomial time algorithms).  Informally, it asks whether every problem whose solution can be quickly verified by a computer can also be quickly solved by a computer. I imagine, if someone solves this computer unsolved problem (finding a polynomial-time running algorithm for a known non-polynomial time problem), then perhaps we could answer your second question in the positive sense, at least for those theorems which involve computable problems. For other types of theorems (say, one non-expressible algorithmically) I cannot imagine at the moment how can one could set up anything that would resemble somehow an 'early warning system' (but it would be interesting, though, if someone could furnish something like that, at least for a restricted problem :-) ).

Answer (score 1):

There is a famous paper by John Milnor, "On fundamental groups of complete affinely flat manifolds", where he conjectures that "every solvable Lie group of dimension $n$ admits a complete affinely flat structure invariant under left translation". This holds for small $n$, but counterexamples are known for $n=11$ by Yves Benoist and for $n=10$ by myself (and Fritz Grunewald for $n=11$).

More precisely, the question involves the following invariant $\mu(L)$ of a given $n$-dimensional Lie algebra $L$ over a field $K$, which is defined as the minimal dimension of a faithful $L$-module.
By Ado's theorem, $\mu (L)<\infty$.

*Conjecture*: Every solvable Lie algebra of dimension $n$ over a field $K$ of characteristic zero satisfies
$$
\mu(L)\le n+1.
$$ 
The counterexamples to Milnor's conjecture correspond to *nilpotent* Lie algebras $L$ of dimension $10$ and $11$, where
$\mu(L)\ge n+2$.

Answer (score 1):

Saw this one recently on [James Grime channel](https://youtu.be/R2eQVqdUQLI): it was conjectured that the sum of every even [amicable pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amicable_numbers) is divisible by 9. The first counterexample is Poulet's pair (the [495th pair](http://oeis.org/A063990/b063990.txt) of amicable numbers) 666030256 and 696630544. The sum of these is 1362660800 = 5 mod 9.

Comment: Ops! Guess I pasted the sum from other place

Answer (score 0):

Numerically, one finds that the function
$$
  f(n) \ := \ \sum_{p \leq n, \\ p \ \text{prime}} \frac{1}{p}
  \left(1 - \frac{1}{\ln(\ln(p))}\right)
$$
appears to take its maximum at $n = 2$.
While already from taking a first glance it is clear that this cannot be, and that $f$ is
unbounded, I claim that it is numerically challenging to find the smallest $n$ for which we have
$f(n) > f(2)$ ... .

Answer (score 0):

The story of [Legendre's constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_constant) seems to qualify. Based on numerical evidence available at the time and the hardness of computing more digits, it was eminently reasonable to conjecture he was not just renaming "1"in his name.

Comment: How is this an example of a counterexample? And where is a "large number" involved?

Comment: @GerryMyerson a large number of terms of the sequence (more than what was achievable at the time?) are needed to compute the constant to sufficiently high precision to rule the conjecture out. (Of course, it could also be disproven directly without those numerical computations.)

Comment: I don't see how any finite number of primes could be used to refute Legendre's conjectured value. That required advances in theory, not computation.

Answer (score 0):

This answer explores further the problem described [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/a/28192/86625), where base-10 numbers that become squares when the digits are repeated twofold are identified (e.g. $13223140496\to1322314049613223140496=36363636364^2$).

In any such square concatenation, the number of digits in each "half" of the square is a value of $n$ for which $10^n+1$ has a squared prime factor. For instance, $10^{11}+1$ is divisible by $11^2$, so there are eleven-digit numbers that become square when concatenated twofold, like the one noted above.

We can identify various solutions for $n$ corresponding to a given squared prime factor by the following process.

1. Select a value of $m$ such that $p|10^m+1$. Such a value of $m$ will be an odd number times half the base-ten repeating decimal period length of $1/p$; the period length itself must be even for the selected $p$ or no solution exists.
2. Render $10^m=K-1$ where $K=10^m+1$ and raise to the power of $p$, writing the right side of $(K-1)^p$ as a polynomial in $K$ via the Binomial Theorem.
3. Each term in that binomial- power expansion is constructed to be a multiple of $p^2$ except the $-1$ term at the end, so $10^{mp}+1$ is a certified multiple of $p^2$.

Results for small primes $p$ suggest that if we choose the minimal value of $m$ for a given factor $p$, then $n=mp$ derived in this way is the *minimal* solution to $p^2|10^n+1$. For instance, $p=11$ pairs with $m=1$ (because $10^1+1$ is $11$ itself), giving $10^{11}+1$ as the smallest augmentedpower of ten divisible by $11^2$. Similarly, $10^8+1$ is the smallest augmented power of ten divisible by $17$, and the solution found by the procedure above, $10^{136}+1$, is the minimal augmented power of ten divisible by $17^2$.

All is as expected until we hit $\color{blue}{p=487}$. The minimal $m$ value is $243$, so we we find from the above lifting procedure that that $487^2|10^{118431}+1$ ... but OEIS sequence [A086981](https://oeis.org/A086981) reports that instead $487^2|10^{243}+1$ as the minimal solution for that factor -- that is, $10^m+1$ instead of $10^{mp}+1$. The minimal solution for that squared prime factor slips in *before* using the binomial power expansion, not after as is usually the case.

Such a counterexample is connected with the fact that any residue $r\bmod p$, maps into $p$ residues $\bmod p^2$. One of these mapped residues is $\equiv r^p$, and this one is a **$p$-power residue** $\bmod p^2$. The other residues $\bmod p^2$ are not $p$-power residues.

For instance, with $p=7$ we render

$10^7\equiv3^7=2187\equiv31\bmod 49,$

so $31$ is a seventh-power residue $\bmod 49$ and other residues congruent to it $\bmod 7$, including $10$, are not seventh-power residues.

With other prime factors that allow a solution to $p|10^m+1$ (and thus also $p^2|10^n+1$), we get the following from residue $10\bmod p$:

$p=11\to10^{11}\equiv120\bmod11^2$

$p=13\to10^{13}\equiv23\bmod13^2$

$p=17\to10^{17}\equiv214\bmod17^2$

...

$p=463\to10^{463}\equiv12974\bmod463^2$

$\color{blue}{p=487\to10^{487}\equiv10\bmod487^2}$

So unlike all smaller primes in scope, $p=487$ renders $10$ a $p$-power residue $\bmod p^2$, causing an extra factor of $p$ to appear in $10^m+1$ for appropriates value of $m$. Hence for this particular case, we did not have to multiply the initial exponent $m=243$ by $487$ to get an augmented power of ten divisible by $487^2$. If we do choose to multiply the exponent, we find that $10^{118341}+1$ is divisible by $487^3$.

The documentation of OEIS A086981 reports no other counterexamples below $1000$. Larger counterexamples are expected to become rare because the $p$-power residue condition becomes less probable for larger primes $p$.

Answer (score -4):

the [Weaire–Phelan structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weaire%25E2%2580%2593Phelan_structure) was found to be

> a better solution of the "Kelvin
> problem" than the previous best-known
> solution, the Kelvin structure.

Comment: This is not a counterexample, eventual or otherwise, in the sense of this question, is it?

Comment: @Gerry really? "The Kelvin conjecture was widely believed and no counter-example was known for more than 100 years, until it was disproved by the discovery of the Weaire–Phelan structure."

Comment: "Eventual", in the sense of this question, does not refer to time, but to number. 