# Small automorphism groups of groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, sequences-and-series, automorphism-groups

I do not know much about group theory, so sorry in case this question is not for MO.
For a finite group $G$, denote by $f(G)$ the number of elements of the automorphism group of $G$.

> Question: For which $n$ is there a unique group with $n$ elements such that $f(G)$ is minimal among all groups with n elements? What is the sequence $a_n$ giving the minimal $f(G)$ for a given $n$.

For $n \leq 63$ (except $n=32$ which has too many groups for my computer it seems and I was not able to finish the calculation with GAP. Ill try it after the holidays with a better computer) it was true that there is a unique such group namely $G=Z/Zn$, so $a_n$ is the Euler totient function $\phi(n)$ for those values.

This suggests the following question:

> Question: Do we have $f(G) \geq \phi(n)$ in case $G$ has $n$ elements?

Comment: Have you looked at [this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1216/RMJ-1979-9-4-653) ? It could contain some helpful information.

Answer (score 9):

The following conjecture is problem 15.43 in [The Kourovka Notebook](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0300), attributed to M. Deaconescu :

> Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$.
>
> a) Is it true that $|Aut(G)|\geq \varphi (n)$ where $\varphi$ is the Euler function?
>
> b) Is it true that $G$ is cyclic if $|Aut(G)|=\varphi (n)$?

The problem is now in the solved section. In fact J. N. Bray and R. A. Wilson in the paper ["On The Orders of Automorphism Groups of Finite Groups"](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/S002460930400400X) show that $\frac{|Aut(G)|}{\varphi(|G|)}$ can be arbitrarily close to zero. And the same holds if we add the extra restrictions of $G$ being perfect or soluble as shown in ["On The Orders of Automorphism Groups of Finite Groups II"](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/jgth.2006.9.issue-4/jgt.2006.036/jgt.2006.036.xml)

The failure of the conjecture in this strong form (ratio can be arbitrarily close to zero) was shown to hold even when restricting to $p$-groups $G$ by J. González-Sánchez and A. Jaikin-Zapirain in ["Finite p-groups with small automorphism group"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/forum-of-mathematics-sigma/article/finite-p-groups-with-small-automorphism-group/639FFEAFAF6847F1765FC6E2757BFB69).

Comment: Thanks, is the smallest n known where a) fails?

Comment: @Mare I don't know if the exact value is known, but a) is true for all groups with $|Aut(G)|\le 48$.

Comment: Maybe this is a good candidate for https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15444/examples-of-eventual-counterexamples .

Comment: A quasisimple counterexample to a) is a perfect group $G$ such that $G/Z(G)\cong PSL_3(4)$, of order $20160$, and $Z(G)\cong Z_2\times Z_4\times Z_3$. This may be the smallest quasisimple counterexample. It exists since the (unusually large) Schur multiplier of $PSL_3(4)$ is $Z_4\times Z_4\times Z_3$.